# Offline sat nav for Android

Tags: gps-navigation

I am pretty sure I saw this already on travel SE, but can't find it now. What are my navigation options with Android phone in an area without data connection? (I am in Northumberland)

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for a turn-by-turn navigation system (mainly for driving). The suggested question is mainly about actual maps without this feature.

Comment: I believe you might have been looking for this as well [GPS app for travelling in France](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26504/gps-app-for-travelling-in-france)

Comment: Or have a look here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82/offline-map-browser-on-android-with-offline-search

Comment: I think this should remain open - this would be a useful "definitive" question, because currently the answers are split between many different questions as we're seeing in these comments.

Comment: @dlanod I think that is the point of marking the question as duplicate: multiple formulations of a question may be satisfied by the same answer. In that case I just come back from a trip when I used the OsmAnd app and this is really a convenient and easy-to-use GPS app (if OSM has good coverage of your area).

Comment: @Vince If multiple variations of a question can all be answered by a definitive version of that question (e.g. offline GPS for UK, France, Germany, etc, all separately) then one definitive question and answer is often more useful and avoids segmentation of answers (like we've seen already).

Answer (score 3):

Recommended software:

- I have used [MapFactor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator), which was recommended to me on this site.  It's free, uses the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) database (also free, with free updates) and is quite usable.  You also pre-download maps so don't have to use 3G downloading as you drive around.
- [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1894/1264) recommends [NavDroyd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator):

  > In addition, you need some serious storage for offline google maps.  What I eventually settled with was [NavDroyd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator) - for Android, but there'll be equivalents for iPhone etc.  It cost a few dollars, but not much - and the maps are all totally free, as they just download the free [Open Street Maps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) maps, which are vector graphics anyway.  It was fantastic.  The interface was a little clunky to me and took a few minutes to get used to, but once I had it sorted it was brilliant - even in Siberia, Kyrgystan and Mongolia!
- [dbkk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/1989/1264) recommended [RMaps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator):

  > A cheap unlocked Android phone with GPS (they start at $120 or so) plus a free offline maps app like [RMaps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapfactor.navigator). You don't need a data connection, but have the option of popping in a cheap local prepaid SIM card for calls and net access.
  >
  > Then you can use [Mobile Atlas Creator 1.8](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) to download relevant maps from different sources before you go (or using a laptop and hotel WiFi while on the road).
- Other software that has been recommended include [OSMAnd](http://osmand.net/), [Sygic](http://www.sygic.com/en/gps-navigation) and [Locus Map](http://www.appbrain.com/app/locus-map-free-outdoor-gps/menion.android.locus).

OSMAnd actually seems to be the most commonly recommended of the lot.